# VGA 15 pin port data read and write using Matlab

Tags: matlab, port, vga

I am using compaq presario cq40 laptop with windows seven ultimate(32-bit OS). I would like to access the 15 pin VGA port using Matlab (preferrably using the Data Acquisition Toolbox). Do I require extra drivers or should download anything from Mathworks.com ??

I have already developed a program for sending digital signal through parallel port (LPT1) using digitalio() function in DAQ toolbox. I intend to use the VGA 15 pin port the same way (since there is no parallel port for the laptop).

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to access the individual pins on a VGA port.

The problem is that the graphics card completely abstracts it away(non-leakyish) so there is no way of working around it, not even at the kernel level.

I would not recommend using the VGA port as a data port anyway though.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know if there are any other options available to send data....Maybe how to send data through usb in matlab??

Comment: I really don't know Matlab much. USB isn't a simple standard either though. You can't control the 4 individual pins there either. Only with LPT and Serial(?) can you do that. It may be a bit overkill, but you may want to get an Arduino and program it so that you can use it as a "proxy" for direct IO access over USB