# Hacking computer hardware to do experiment control

Tags: hardware

I am a physicist, and I had a revelation a few weeks ago about how I might be able to use my personal computer to get much finer control over laboratory experiments than is typically the case.  Before I ran off to try this out though, I wanted to check the feasibility with people who have more expertise than myself in such matters.

The idea is to use the i/o ports---VGA, ethernet, speaker jacks, etc.---on the computer to talk directly to the sensors and actuators in the experimental setup.  E.g. cut open one side of an ethernet cable (with the other end attached to the computer) and send each line to a different device.  I knew a postdoc who did something very similar using a BeagleBone.  He wrote some assembly code that let him sync everything with the internal clock and used the GPIO pins to effectively give him a hybrid signal generator/scope that was completely programmable.  It seems like the same thing should be possible with a laptop, and this would have the additional benefit that you can do data analysis from the same device.

The main potential difficulty that I foresee is that the hardware on a BeagleBone is designed with this sort of i/o in mind, whereas I expect the hardware on a laptop will probably be harder to control directly.  I know for example (from some preliminary investigation, http://ask.metafilter.com/125812/Simple-USB-control-how-to-blink-an-LED-via-code) that USB ports will be difficult to access this way, and VGA is (according to [VGA 15 pin port data read and write using Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126282/vga-15-pin-port-data-read-and-write-using-matlab)) impossible.  I haven't found anything about using other ports like ethernet or speaker jacks, though.

So the main question is: will this idea be feasible (without investing many months for each new variation of the hardware), and if so what type of i/o (ethernet, speaker jacks, etc.) is likely to be the best bet?

Auxiliary questions are:

1. Where can I find material to learn how I might go about executing this plan?  I'm not even sure what keywords to plug in on Google.
2. Will the ease with which I can do this depend strongly on operating system or hardware brand?

Comment: lowly parallel ports contain at least 8 fast (>64khz) switches for output and 8 fast  "buttons" (short sensors) for input, and are implemented by reading/writing writing a single memory address with an 8-bit value, aka one byte. for input, you can hack up a cheap USB gamepad and solder leads onto the button membrane contacts, giving you a fast 10-channel discrete input controller for under $20.

Comment: outputs from the PC are harder, but cheap options include numlock lights, speakers, vibration/feedback gamepads, usb flash drive LEDs (ping disk to activate), ejecting a rom drive tray, photosensors and blinking rectangles on a monitor, and of course: lots of stuff you buy for the task (boo).

Comment: Most modern PC's are very poor in the simple-IO department, and what interfaces they do have (such as USB) tend to be surprisingly high latency. If you want close coupling to the real world you will want an embedded processor with direct GPIO such as the ARM SOC on your friend's beaglebone, and not a consumer laptop.

Comment: I would start by finding out what controller chips you have on your laptop, then google for those. I would expect you to mainly find proof-of-concept DIY projects like garage door controllers, simple home irrigation systems, etc. I'm biased, but I'd definitely go with Linux for this - even if Microsoft's agenda isn't necessarily to obstruct this sort of thing (what with "Developers Developers Developers" and all) I would not be at all surprised if you quickly started to bump into little "Warranty Void" stickers in the form of unintuitive, unstable, and/or undocumented APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The only cable I can think of for a pc that can get close to this would be a parallel printer cable which is pretty much gone away. It's a 25 wire cable that data is spread across so that it can send more data at the same time. I'm just not sure if you can target a specific line or if it's more of a left to right fill as data is sent.

To use one on a laptop today would definitely be difficult. You won't find any laptops with parallel ports. There are usb to parallel cables and serial to parallel cables but I would guess that the only control you would have it to the usb or serial interface and not the parallel.

As for Ethernet, you have 4 twisted pair with only 2 pair in use and 2 pair that are extra.

There's some hardware that available called Zwave that you might want to look into. Zwave will allow you to build a network of devices that communicate in a mesh. I'm not sure what kind of response time you need.

I actually just thought of something that might be a good solution. Check out security equipment. There's a lot of equipment available for pc's that monitor doors, windows, sensors, etc. That industry might what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use the USB port as a Human Interface Device (HID) and using a custom built PIC program and a PIC that includes the USB functionality to encode the data to be sent to the computer and in that way be able to program it independently from the OS due to the fact that all mayor OS have the HID USB functionality.

Anyways if you used your MIC/VGA/HDMI whatever other port you still need a device to encode the data or transmit it, and another program inside the computer to decode that data being sent.

And remember that different hardware has different software (drivers) that might decode the raw data in other odd ways rendering your IO hardware dependent.

Hope this helps, but thats why the USB was invented in the first place to make it hardware and os independent.